# Financial technical analysis in python

Tags: python, finance

Do you know if there is any financial technical analysis module available for python ? Need to calculate various indicators such as RSI, EMA, DEMA etc for a project

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here are a few thoughts... I have only used Numpy, Scipy, and Matplotlib for financial calculations.

- [py-fi](http://www.advogato.org/proj/py-fi/) - very basic financial functions
- [fin2py](https://code.google.com/p/fin2py/) - financial tools
- [Numpy/Scipy](http://www.scipy.org) - covers all of the statistics basics
- [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net) - plotting financial functions
- [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) - a Python interface to R allowing use of R libraries
- [ystockquote](http://www.goldb.org/ystockquote.html) - Python API for Yahoo! Stock Data
- [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org) - Open source library (supposedly has Python Bindings)
- [PyFinancial](http://code.google.com/p/pyfinancial/) - Docs in Spanish
- [PyMacLab](https://github.com/escheffel/pymaclab/) - "Series of classes useful for conducting research in dynamic macroeconomics"
- [TSDB](http://code.google.com/p/tsdb/) - for storing large volumes of time series data
- [PyVol](http://code.google.com/p/pyvol/) - volatility estimation of financial time series

Comment: Came across this question on google. The github link below also has a good list of useful libraries/tools for many languages, including Python: https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/awesome-quant

Answer (score 29):

[TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org/) - Library of indicators. 
[How to compile for Python](http://blog.mediafederation.com/andy-hawkins/getting-ta-lib-to-work-with-python-2-6-swig-interface/)

Comment: You might also find this [TA-Lib python wrapper](http://mrjbq7.github.com/ta-lib/) to be useful.

Comment: Christo, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: For windows users, I recommend using the [compiled binary of the TA-Lib python wrapper](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) instead of going through dependency hell.

Answer (score 15):

There is also a [Computational Finnance Course](https://www.coursera.org/course/compinvesting1) on [Coursera.org](http://coursera.org).

They use a Python Open Source Library called [QSTK (QuantSoftware ToolKit)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151202145050/http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=QuantSoftware_ToolKit).
They have a bunch of [tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20151127190451/http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=QSTK_Tutorial_1) on the wiki page and you can always take the course
if you want to learn more.

For convenience I copied the description from the wiki page below:

> QSToolKit (QSTK) is a Python-based open source software framework
> designed to support portfolio construction and management. We are
> building the QSToolKit primarily for finance students, computing
> students, and quantitative analysts with programming experience. You
> should not expect to use it as a desktop app trading platform.
> Instead, think of it as a software infrastructure to support a
> workflow of modeling, testing and trading.
>
> ```
> Scroll through the Gallery to see the sorts of things you can do easily with QSTK.
> If you are in a hurry, you can skip to the QSToolKit_Installation_Guide.
> ```
>
> Key components of QSTK are:
>
> ```
> - Data: A data access package that enables fast reading of 
>   historical data (qstkutil.DataAccess).
> - Processing tools: Uses pandas, a Python package designed for time series 
>   evaluation of equity data.
> - Portfolio optimization: Using the CVXOPT library.
> - Event studies: An efficient event analyzer, Event_Profiler.
> - Simulation: A simple backtester, quicksim, 
>   that includes transaction cost modeling.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You might find this repository of technical indicators useful. The library works similarly to the famous ta-lib library, and contains indicators that were not implemented in talib

[talibextensions](https://github.com/tomyitav/talib-extensions)

For example, you can use the Highest high, lowest low indicator, by sending high and low vectors, plus number of periods, in the following way: (Extracted from the test in the repository)

```
    from indicators import TalibExtension
    hhllMatrix = TalibExtension.HHLL(self.high, self.low, 5);
```