# Financial python library

Tags: python, finance

I'm looking for a python library that provides simple set of financial calculations, such as MACD, EMAs and other indicators. I've been looking around for it, but either all projects that were trying to do it are dead, or non-existent. Is there a library like that in the existence?

Thanks.

Comment: A similar question was posted here about a month earlier
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406481/technical-analysis-in-python

Answer (score 2):

ActiveState has a [recommendation](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/06/must-have-python-packages-finance) for must have python packages when dealing with finance industry related problems. Did you check that and does that contain whatever you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I have, and no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org/). Pandas may have all the tools to build these calculations from scratch, but this library has virtually all the common technical indicators you could ask for already made into simple functions.

Answer (score 0):

pandas has all the tools needed to to these computations.  It has methods for moving averages exponential moving averages etc.   very easy to do the technical indicators if you already have the time series data in pandas data structures.

can also look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html bit of a long example, but it gives a very nicely formatted MACD plot.